# Does jQuery support canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, canvas

In my application I need to use canvas and its events. Does jQuery and/or jQuery UI support canvas and canvas events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're asking. Because `<canvas>` is a DOM element, jQuery can interact with it to a certain extent. You might want to check out [this article](http://motyar.blogspot.com/2010/04/drawing-on-web-with-canvas-and-jquery.html), which, although terribly written and formatted, does demonstrate interaction between jQuery and the `<canvas>` tag.

Comment: I am asking whether can use jquery event syntax(on, live,delegate,etc) with canvas events? Wheter Jquery UI support any drag and drop inside canvas? etc

Comment: I'm fairly sure the answer is no to that, I'm afraid. jQuery UI and jQuery event syntax depends on having DOM elements to manipulate, and the `<canvas>` tag doesn't use DOM elements. Sorry.

Comment: However, have you checked out RaphaelJS (http://raphaeljs.com/)? It supports drawing functionality similar to what `<canvas>` provides, but it also works with jQuery. I'm using it on one of the projects I'm currently working on and I like it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

if you're referring to the specific api for the canvas tag, then not directly. There are plugins that will help you communicate with the canvas tag however:

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/canvas

Comment: Dis you check that link your self? It's showing "The plugins site is currently in development."

Comment: You should try scrolling down the page.

Comment: Thanks. But I have not able to find something like support canvas events.